# Append a parent Div for another Div with React js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, appendchild

I would like to do this http://jsfiddle.net/bosworth99/ejdRf/4/ with react js

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slides"></div>
</div>

function wrap() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.setAttribute("id", "slideInner");
  document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(newDiv);
  newDiv.appendChild(document.getElementById('slides'));
}
```

Comment: You should provide what you've done so for to tackle the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways for doing that. One way could be the following:

One component `Parent` with the background-color property:

```
function Parent({ children }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100px", width: "100px", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

One component `Children` with the `border` property:

```
function Child() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        height: "100px",
        width: "100px",
        border: "4px solid black"
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

And a `Component` that displays only the `Parent` or both Components depending on a boolean `visible`:

`<Parent>{visible ? <Child /> : null}</Parent>`

The full component:

```
function App() {
  const [visible, toggleVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => toggleVisible(!visible)}>Show Parent</button>       
        <Parent>{visible ? <Child /> : null}</Parent>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-thunder-voy1r

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following React snippet

It uses react-hooks to know a state value `inner` and based on its value, the dom structure is dynamically generated

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Slide = () => {
  const [inner,setInner] = useState(false); //using react hooks for cleaner code, you can use class based states also
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setInner(true),2500); //same as the logic in the fiddle shared
  },[]) // same as ComponentDidMount in class based component

  const getWrappedDOM = () => {
    if(inner) {
      return (<div id="slideInner"><div id="slides"></div></div>);
    } else {
      return (<div id="slides"></div>);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      {getWrappedDOM(); // generates the required DOM structure}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I need something like newDiv.appendChild(document.getElementById('slides')); to append to an existing element beacuse i have a lot of nodes inside <div id="slides"></div>, so i cant put in the your condition above